# Asymptotic expansion of Riemann's prime counting function

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

Riemann's [prime counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html) is given as

$$J(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\operatorname{li}(n^{1/k})$$

the approximations

\begin{align}
\operatorname{li}(n)\sim J(n)\tag{1}\\
\operatorname{li}(n)-\sqrt{n}/\log n\sim J(n)\tag{2}\\
(1-\sqrt{n}/\log n)\operatorname{li}(n+\sqrt{n}\log n)\sim J(n)\tag{3}\\
\end{align}

get increasingly closer. Could these be the first few terms of an asymptotic expansion of $J(n),$ or can $(3)$ not be taken any further?

Comment: Small typo in the definition of prime counting function: $li(n^{1/k})$.

Comment: In what sense is the question not answered in your MathWorld link? They write it as the "Gram Series".

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't think the Gram series is the same as the form as given above - if it is, I can't see it - am I missing something?

Comment: It is not the same, but it IS an asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear $\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} li(x^{1/k})$ is **not** a prime counting function.

The prime counting functions are $$\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \log p, \quad J(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{1}{k} = \int_{2-\epsilon}^x \frac{\psi'(y)}{\log y} dy = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\pi(x^{1/k})}{k}, \quad \pi(x) = \sum_{p \le x} 1$$ 
Whose Mellin transforms are $\frac{-1}{s}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)},\frac{1}{s}\log \zeta(s),\frac{1}{s}P(s) $.

The (Riemann) explicit formulas are $$\psi(x) = x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} - \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{x^{-2m}}{-2m}-\log 2 \pi, \\J(x) = \text{Li}(x)- \sum_\rho \text{Li}(x^\rho) - \sum_{m\ge 1} \text{Li}(x^{-2m})-A, \\\pi(x) = R(x) -  \sum_\rho R(x^\rho)  - \sum_{m\ge 1} R(x^{-2m})-B,\\ \text{Li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dy}{\log y}, \qquad R(x ) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \text{Li}(x^{1/k})$$

Comment: @martin what is your question then ? Do you see why $\text{Li}(x)$ is easier than $\text{li}(x) =  \int_0^x \text{pv.}(\frac{1}{\log y}) dy$ ?

Comment: I am from Europe, so maybe that's where the confusion lies!

Comment: @martin The confusion of what ? See [apostol](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/IntrodAnalyticNTApostol.pdf)'s book about analytic number theory.

Comment: sorry - I meant my confusion when referencing

Comment: @reuns: Where did you take the formula for $J(x)$?  It is “not even wrong”: the summation in $m$ makes no sense when used with “your Li”.  To make the formula correct, one should replace the first and third Li by li, replace $A$ by $\log 2$, and replace the second $\operatorname{Li}(x^ρ)$ by $-E_1(-ρ\log x)$.

Comment: For example, with summing over the first 2·10⁶ roots ρ and $x=4.567$, the error term (with my corrections) is about 3.3·10⁻⁷.  (I can see the formula as you wrote it in Landau Handbuch 1909 Band I S.361, with your Li defined on S.48.  Unfortunately, it makes no sense!)